# Post-fix expression solver

Tags: c++

The objective was to write a program that will solve post-fix/reverse Polish notation expressions. It seemed to be and easy task, but I seem to be overlooking the error in this.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
vector<int> stack;
string input;

cout << "Please enter post-fix expression to be evaluated (+, -, *, /): ";
cin >> input;

for(int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
{
    if(input[i] == '+')
    {
        int temp1 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();
        int temp2 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();

        int sum = temp1 + temp2;
        stack.push_back(sum);
    }
    else if(input[i] == '-')
    {
        int temp1 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();
        int temp2 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();

        int difference = temp1 - temp2;
        stack.push_back(difference);
    }
    else if(input[i] == '*')
    {
        int temp1 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();
        int temp2 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();

        int product = temp1 * temp2;
        stack.push_back(product);
    }
    else if(input[i] == '/')
    {
        int temp1 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();
        int temp2 = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();

        int quotient = temp1 / temp2;
        stack.push_back(quotient);
    }
    else
    {
        stack.push_back(input[i]);
    }
}

cout << "Result: " << stack.back();
```

Comment: Well, for starters `input[i] == '+'` is attempting to compare an `int` to a `char`. Secondly, since `'+'` is not an `int`, `cin >> input` is never going to successfully read a `'+'`.

Comment: Secondly you have the operands for - and / in the wrong order.

Comment: This is a perfect question for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but not for stackoverflow.

Comment: The real problem is `stack.push_back(input[i]);` you push back a char, for example '7', which will cause 55 to be pushed on the stack.

Comment: 'input' is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is stack.push_back(input[i]); you push back a char, for example '7', which will cause 55 to be pushed on the stack.